# ORM entity concept

Tags: database-design, orm

I'm writing my own ORM framework and I have questions about where to put code responsible for executing SQL commands. Execute SQL commands should be invoked in entity class or maybe in external database manager? Do you know how this is handled in other ORM frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own ORM in the 1990's to work with VB5 and VB6 and RDO with SQL Server.  I applied the principle of separation of concerns to the generated code such that there were three layers of code generated by my ORM CASE tool:

- Transact SQL stored procedures for CRUD operations and searching/listing operations
- VB code for operating the database layer (this is where the RDO-specific stuff lived)
- Business rule code (this is where edits and defaults would be applied)

This separation made the code more logical and allowed me to isolate changes to the code when RDO needed to be converted to ADO.NET, for example.  It also meant that I didn't have to read past reams of database boilerplate to be able to see and modify business logic related code or vice versa, read through business rules to find the place where a SQL Server column name needed to be changed.